# What is the shell exactly when using Cmder on Windows?

Tags: windows, terminal, shell, operating-systems, emulator

I've just started using Cmder on Windows 7 and I understand that is a console emulator for Windows which gives a better experience than using cmd. However as I understand it the emulator needs to run a shell in order to communicate the user commands to the OS, so on windows what is the shell here? is CMD the default shell for Windows?

Would appreciate just understanding how these tools are connected.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell

Comment: The Windows shell is the default shell for Windows, CMD is retained for backwards compatibility and convenience and because GUIs suck sometimes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMMAND.COM#Operating_modes

Comment: Ok, so when cmder is run by default it uses the windows shell? the windows shell is a graphical user interface from that wiki link though? So cmder is passing the commands to the GUI shell??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows comes with two command-line shells built-in: Cmd.exe and PowerShell 5. (The Windows GUI is indeed a "shell" in one sense, but it is not a *command* shell, and not applicable to the question.)

Cmder uses Cmd.exe by default, but *heavily* customizes it – the actual interactive prompt that you see isn't a normal Cmd.exe prompt; it is shown by ConEmu's `clink` which gets injected into the Cmd process. (The whole "Cmder" window is actually [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/).)

So technically all your commands still run through Cmd, but it is the injected Clink library that provides advanced features like tab-completion and Readline-like keybindings.

But besides Cmd.exe, it is possible to run [any other shell](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder#features) in Cmder, such as PowerShell or Bash (which isn't part of Windows, but is standard on Linux and often gets installed along with Git For Windows as well).

> However as I understand it the emulator needs to run a shell in order to communicate the user commands to the OS

In a sense yes, although shells aren't necessary to just "run" commands (any process can start any .exe file at any time; that's how one creates a shell in the first place); rather their job is to *interpret* commands – they provide things like if/for/while loops, %variable% expansion, etc. Besides that, however, they do not have any special access to OS facilities that other programs wouldn't.<sup>1</sup>

(So in theory, a terminal *could* display its own prompts and implement its own command language, it's just rarely done because most people are quite used to e.g. the Bash syntax.)

---

<sup>1</sup> (This applies to Windows and all Unix-like systems, but not neccessarily to *all* operating systems. For example, the DCL command shell in OpenVMS is actually more privileged than normal programs, as was the case in many operating systems at the time – it was likely Unix that broke the tradition, with its shell being a completely normal and replaceable tool.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had a hunch that cmder was running cmd under the hood but do you have a reference for this anywhere, I couldn't find one? Also is it possible in Windows to see which shell is running using a command e,g, the way you can in unix with echo $0?

Comment: I looked at the process tree using ProcExp (or Process Hacker) which showed cmd.exe running as a child of ConEmu.exe, and then tried using several Cmd-specific commands (it has many built-ins such as 'if' and 'for' with their own syntax, as well as many distinct syntax quirks overall).

Comment: Thanks, just want to clarify a few other things you mentioned. You said that bash shell can be run in cmder, but is this the real bash, or a bash emulator that uses aliases etc to make it seem like bash?

Comment: The other point I thought was interesting was that I had the impression that shells specifically provided access to parts of the OS or a kernel that a user wouldn't be able to access otherwise, it seems that's not true from your answer. Thanks for the info, it helps

Comment: "Bash" that is installed with e.g. Git or Cygwin is indeed real GNU Bash, just compiled as a Windows .exe instead of a Linux binary. It usually comes with Windows versions of real GNU Coreutils and other tools, as well (e.g. `ls` in PowerShell is an alias, but `ls` in Bash runs real GNU Coreutils 'ls').

Comment: And, well, to clarify – most things that you run through Bash _aren't part of Bash,_ they're external commands. Bash does have a few builtins, but e.g. while Cmd.exe has `dir` built-in (there's no dir.exe), that's not the case for the `ls` command in Bash – it's a fully external program that even comes from a different project, and the same `/bin/ls` or `ls.exe` could be run from any shell.